# Security Exception with tabbar one touch email composer

Tags: android

My goal is that on a tabbar when you push the tabs different activities show but on one of them I want no activity just an email account chooser to show leading to the email composer.

My current method is working on 2.2 and 2.3 but not on anything higher. So on a Galaxy 3s I get

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Given caller package android is not running in process ProcessRecord{}
```

Here is my current code, I am up for doing a better way also if you have constructive criticism.

public class myTabbar extends TabActivity {

```
TabHost tabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    setTabs();
}

private void setTabs() {
    addTab("Home", R.drawable.home, Home_Page_Activity.class);
    addTab("Map", R.drawable.map, Map_Locations_Activity.class);
    addTab("Email", R.drawable.email, Email_From_Tab.class);    
    addTab("Input", R.drawable.suggestions, Suggestions_Activity.class);
    addTab("More", R.drawable.more, More.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {           
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);     
        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);      
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        if(c == Email_From_Tab.class){
            Intent it=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
            String[] tos={"email@emael.com"};     
            String[] ccs={"email@emael.com"};     
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos);     
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, ccs);     
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The email body text");     
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The email subject text"); 
            it.setType("message/rfc822"); 

            spec.setContent(Intent.createChooser(it, "Choose Email Client"));
        }else{
            spec.setContent(intent);
        }
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed third-party activities into your own UI this way.

Comment: OK. I also tried just starting another activity with no layout.xml that just started the createChooser. Which worked but if you left the tab and went back then it would not show again. So I added it to the onResume, that however caused a loop that you could not back out of.  Would I be on the right path there if I continued in that direction?

Comment: @Rick: Since I have no idea what you consider "the right path" to be, I cannot answer that. You cannot embed a third-party activity into your own tab set. Not to mention that embedding activities in tabs has been deprecated for over two years.